# export MySQL workbench schema as JSON file

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I want to generate some data on Mockaroo

https://mockaroo.com/schemas/import

In my MySQL Workbench I have a working database schema and want to export this structure as a JSON schema because Mockaroo is not able to import a `.mwb` file.

Is there a way to export the schema as JSON?

Here you can see the export dialog in the workbench

[image: Export]

Comment: It would be much easier, I think, to just export your schema in CSV format.  Is that not a possibility on either end for you?

Comment: When trying to export it I can just export as PNG, SVG and PDF it seems .. ?

Comment: If you are being offered the chance to save your data as a PNG file, then something is off.

Comment: I added a picture from the export dialog

Comment: You can do Database->Forward Engineer..., open MySQL Connection and do Server->Data Export, there you can choose export to SQL file. And finally use SQL to JSON converter - you can find one in google - to generate JSON file.